# How to use a different reporter with Vows' run() method?

Tags: node.js, vows

Vows has a run() method that runs the test under node, without using the `vows` command.

At https://github.com/cloudhead/vows/blob/master/lib/vows/suite.js we can see that this method takes an option parameter which allows to specify a reporter other than the default:

```
this.run = function (options, callback) {
    var that = this, start;

    options = options || {};

    for (var k in options) { this.options[k] = options[k] }

    this.matcher  = this.options.matcher  || this.matcher;
    this.reporter = this.options.reporter || this.reporter;
```

What value is supposed to be passed in the options object to select a different reporter, for instance the `spec` reporter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
var spec = require("vows/lib/vows/reporters/spec");
// ...
vows.describe("My Tests").addBatch({ /* some batch */ }).run({reporter:spec});
```

This was the simplest way that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need an instance of a reporter. Only one of them is public (the dot reporter) as `vows.options.reporter`

Other then that you can rip out any of the reporters in the [vows reporter folder](https://github.com/cloudhead/vows/tree/master/lib/vows/reporters). and include it manually.

The alternatives would be to export the vows suite (`.export(module)`) and call `$ vows --spec` or `$ vows --json`.

[vows-is](https://github.com/Raynos/vows-is) also offers a [reporter](https://github.com/Raynos/vows-is#is.reporter) that's similar to the "spec" reporter.

I guess you could open an issue on vows for making the reporters public.

Comment: @FernandoCorreia if you have general or vague questions your always welcome to drop into the [node.js chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/642/node-js)

Comment: I actually asked that in #node.js earliear but got no answer. But thx for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the require to reporter is already did at vows/lib/vows/suite.js

```
    if (options.reporter) {
      try {
        this.reporter = typeof options.reporter === 'string'
            ? require('./reporters/' + options.reporter)
            : options.reporter;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Reporter was not found, defaulting to dot-matrix.');
      }
    }
```

Then, to use it, you should just:

```
vows.describe('Your suite').addBatch({
    // your batch in here
    }).run({reporter:'spec'}, function(testResults){
        log(testResults);
})
```